# "два мужчины" or "двое мужчин"?

Tags: грамматика

Is it okay to say "два мужчины" or should I always say "двое мужчин"?

Comment: See also: [human animate plural - двое, трое](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/4498/551).

Comment: you can compare usage rates here: [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=два+мужчины,двое+мужчин&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=25&smoothing=3)

Comment: Usage rates can only represent the fact that situations where one should prefer the first version here (like when speaking about men in personal life) are relatively rare, and that is natural.

Comment: Some authors (like Т. Янко) point out that certain native speakers prefer the form "двое мужчин" even when the situation *may* require to use the form "два мужчины" instead, and the discussion in comments proves it. The question concerns a *live* part of the language where developing processes take place, so, paradoxically, both answers are true: "Yes, *sometimes* it's okay to say "два мужчины", though you may choose to *always* say "двое мужчин", and that is okay too".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You usually say "двое мужчин" if you consider them 'a group' (e.g. they came together, do something together, do the same thing, etc.).

```
Из-за угла вышли двое мужчин.
```

Here's an example, where "два мужчины" is more correct (how many; different times or places).

```
В моей жизни было два мужчины.
```

A real example:

```
   Анастасия Вертинская: "У меня в жизни только два мужчины, 
    которых я по-настоящему люблю. Это мой отец и сын Степан..."
```

**P.S.** A reference, by request and as opposed to the quoted web source where "два мужчины" was called *impossible* expression.

*Жилина О.А., Романова Н.Н. - Русский язык и культура речи. ч.1. Основы культуры речи - 2008*

http://psyera.ru/upotreblenie-sobiratelnyh-chislitelnyh_8716.htm

II. Числительные собирательные и количественные употребляются **как синонимы**:

1) с субстантивированными прилагательными и причастиями мужского рода: двое прохожих - два прохожих, трое больных -три больных, двое отдыхающих - два отдыхающих (предпочтительнее собирательные числительные);

2) с существительными мужского и общего рода, имеющими окончание -а: **двое мужчин - два мужчины**, трое старост - три старосты, трое сирот - три сироты (предпочтительнее собирательные числительные);

Comment: Can you please cite any sources?

Comment: Here are 2 pages from the handbook "Трудности русского языка" (Вакуров, Рахманова, Формановская - "Флинта", 2011) discussing general aspects of choice between двое/два (две). Unfortunately, no examples of alternative numerals used in different situations with the same noun.

https://books.google.ru/books?id=UVllAAAAQBAJ&hl=ru&hl=ru&pg=PA133&img=1&zoom=3&ots=EBnMOmda_e&sig=ACfU3U0vUweHMVI8lh1Vo8KBbsCPwwGAhA&w=685

https://books.google.ru/books?id=UVllAAAAQBAJ&hl=ru&hl=ru&pg=PA134&img=1&zoom=3&ots=EBnMOmda_e&sig=ACfU3U3dAkRrKz5ZHg2up9jDEtgHqSiYIQ&w=685

Comment: @Alex_ander Your source actually confirms that "два мужчины" is wrong.

Comment: The recommended "двое мужчин, вернувшихся с работы" is definitely within the concept I gave (they both came there after doing the same).

Comment: Provided reference contradicts one of the recommended answers.  The reference explicitly states that the usage of the word "два" with nouns denoting male persons is impossible.  The word "двое" should be used instead.  Please provide reference that supports both of your advices.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of sources to clear the topic:

[Два, две или двое?](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200801009) (edited)

По правилам русского языка, если речь о *женщинах*, *девушках* и *девочках*, употребляются количественные числительные *две*, *три*, *четыре* и т.д.: две женщины, три девушки, четыре девочки. Если же речь о *мужчинах*, *юношах* и *мальчиках*, их уже будет *двое*, *трое*, *четверо*. Сказать: «Иду я по парку, а навстречу мне *два мужчины*» абсолютно невозможно. Хоть слово мужчина (как и юноша) по форме напоминает слово женщина, оно – мужского рода – значит, навстречу идут *двое мужчин*. Итак, мужчин и юношей не может быть два, три, четыре. А вот мальчиков может быть и два, и двое.

Собирательные числительные идут в ход и тогда, когда имеются в виду вообще люди или дети: вот по улице, например, идут *двое* или *двое прохожих* (двое мужчин, две женщины или мужчина и женщина – не суть важно), а за ними – четверо ребят (опять-таки, это могут быть и мальчишки, и девчонки, или и те, и другие).

Если мы имеем дело с сочетанием *трое сирот*, нельзя сразу сказать, кто имеется в виду: мальчики или девочки (могут быть и те, и другие, или, например, двое мальчиков и одна девочка), если же упомянуты *три сироты* – речь однозначно о девочках, лишившихся родителей.

Есть случаи, когда можно сказать и так, и этак: *два друга* и *двое друзей*. В первом словосочетании смысловой акцент – на личностях, это два конкретных человека, которые дружат, во втором – скорее на том, что их объединяет.

Не рекомендуется употреблять собирательные числительные, если речь идет о людях, занимающих высокое положение. Например, на кафедре может быть *два профессора* (но не *двое профессоров*), а в воинском подразделении – *три генерала* (но не *трое генералов*). Количественные числительные и в этом случае позволяют сделать акцент на личности, на ее достижениях, а собирательные – «понижают статус» соответствующего лица (ср. двое преподавателей, трое военных – здесь акцент скорее на социальной группе).

To go deeper:

[Русский язык в научном освещении, №1 (3), 2002](http://www.ruslang.ru/doc/rjano03.pdf)

Многие информанты весьма настороженно относятся к форме *два мужчины*, избегая ее и предпочитая ей в тех случаях, когда отсутствуют семантические запреты на сочетаемость с собирательным числительным, форму с двое: *двое мужчин*. Частотность сочетаний типа *два мужчины* действительно невелика. Идиолекту автора статьи формы *два мужчины* и *два юноши* не чужды. Однако мы не можем не считаться с тем, что статистика говорит не в пользу сочетания *два мужчины*. [...] такие формы, как *три/четыре мужчины*, а также в некоторых
идиолектах и *два мужчины*, оказываются на периферии нормы.

Comment: "Трое девушек" - совершенно нормально

Comment: @Anixx, при всём уважении, так же как и "два мужчины", в настоящее время сочетание "трое девушек" всё ещё находится на периферии литературной нормы и употребляется скорее в неформальной разговорной речи (например, в паре "трое ребят – трое девчат"); в (классических) литературных произведениях такое выражение вряд ли можно встретить, равно и в школьном сочинении/изложении это будте признано ошибкой

Answer (score 1):

No, no one says "*два мужчины*". Can't really remember any setting where this could be right. Though you may say "*два мужика*".

Comment: http://www.7ya.ru/article/Dva-lyubimyh-muzhchiny-ili-Kak-vyrastaet-lyubov/ Would you say "двое любимых мужчин/мужиков" instead?

Comment: @Alex_ander "Двое любимых мужчин". See no why it should be different in this case, except wrong "feminish"-way "сюсюканье".

Comment: Even in case the second one appeared after death of the first one?

Comment: @Alex_ander Yes.

Comment: How would you transform the expression "это два разных мужчины"?

Comment: @Alex_ander "Двое разных мужчин" or "Два разных человека".

Comment: Like in this context: http://woowx.com/status/love/615--ya-lyublyu-i-lyubima-pozdravlyayu-ne-s-chem-eto-dva-raznyh-muzhchiny.html

Comment: @Alex_ander Again, I could say (and I'd prefer to) "Это двое разных мужчин". Nothing wrong in "двое" here.

Comment: The problem is that "двое" tends to unite those mentioned, while the idea of that phrase is to express difference or apartness.

Comment: @Alex_ander The word "разные" shows this, and nothing else matters here. Saying just "Это два мужчины" wouldn't mean anything about their difference.

Comment: How about "в прошлом месяце в разных частях города были найдены два убитых мужчины" - тоже "двое"? Для меня это звучит так, будто они при жизни сговорились так залечь.

Comment: @Alex_ander По мне так и здесь "двое убитых" звучит лучше.

Comment: @all: your discussion proves that it's more a question of practical language usage, rather than theoretical grammar or strict rules – the form "двое мужчин" has an overpoweringly higher usage rate in comparison with the form "два мужчины", so even in cases when "два мужчины" may for some reasons be more appropriate, the more habitual form "двое мужчин" normally wins the competition

Comment: a deeper research on the topic: Т. Е. Янко "Русские числительные как классификаторы существительных", [Русский язык в научном освещении, №1 (3), 2002](http://www.ruslang.ru/doc/rjano03.pdf)